# Eclipse C++ - Direct Download Links

Tags: eclipse, curl, eclipse-cdt

I run a docker image where i need to pull eclipse c++ automatically with a direct link.
This works with either wget or curl with all other dependencies, but not eclipse, as they dont post direct download links on their download page.

is there a solution to get direct download links? where is the official VCS repository or the location of their artefacts?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that the download links on the [Eclipse download page](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) will take you to another page to confirm or to select a mirror.

For a direct download link you have the following option:

- On the page to confirm or to select a mirror click on *Select Another Mirror* and get the link to a specific mirror
- Add `&r=1` to the URL which redirects to the file at a mirror (not to a HTML page)
- Add `&mirror_id=1` to the URL to not use a mirror and download the file from eclipse.org

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for posting, i found the location:

http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.eclipse.org/eclipseMirror/technology/epp/downloads/release/2020-12/R/eclipse-cpp-2020-12-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

But to be fair, eclipse hides this well on their official website.